# How to disable automatic panning on marker touch in Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, maps, android-maps-v2

In [this Android Design in Action video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FocGotjZ8r4&feature=player_detailpage#t=1665), they recommend dissabling automatic panning when the info window on a map fits the screen to prevent the touch targets to change each time the user touches a marker. However, I have not found any example on how to do that.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may suppress the default panning behaviour by setting your `GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener` and returning `true` (handled) there. You will have to call `marker.showInfoWindow()` to still show the info window.

Making this conditional is a bit harder. Most likely you will have to use `InfoWindowAdapter` and layout `View` before returning it yourself, using its width, height, `LatLng` of the `Marker` converted to `Point` on screen to calculate if it will fit the screen.

You may also post a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2) for that. Such conditional default behaviour would be better UX and they got all the data to make this calculation simpler.

Comment: This seems to be the way to do it and I could do it following your suggestions. Thank you.